# Javascript & Canvas: Endless random animation of slightly morphing circle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm completely new to `canvas` and animating objects with it. I did a little bit of research (e.g. I found [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html)) however I couldn't find any general answer or tutorial on how to create a "morphing" circle.

[image]

The image I posted here is what I would like to do:
I'd like to create `one` circle that is `endlessly` animated via a `randomizer` and is slightly morphing its contours.

I know this might be not a "real" question for this forum, however I just wonder if anyone could provide a few tipps or tricks on how to do something like that.

By "how to do something like that" I'm speaking actually about the technique on how to morph a circle. Do I have to "mathematically" create a circle with dozens of anchor-points along the edge that are influenced by a randomized function?

I would really appreciate some starting help with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A circle can be reasonably well approximated by 4 cubic curves (one for each quarter and the control points on the tangents - google for the correct length of the control segments or calculate them yourself - see [here](http://www.whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/). You could then randomly animate the control points within a small radius to get a wobbling effect.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to "mathematically" create a circle with dozens of anchor-points along the edge that are influenced by a randomized function?

Yes, you do, although it should not be necessary to create "dozens".

You may find the `.bezierCurveTo()` and `.quadraticCurveTo()` functions useful to provide smooth interpolated curves between control points.

Answer (score 0):

When you can use a raster image then for every point you can displace it along the x-axis with a sin function. You can run the same function along the y-axis but instead to simply displace the pixel you can double it. This should give you a morphing circle but it also works with other shapes.